# Unable to locate Spark Jar: Java ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jar, apache-spark

I am installing Spark on Ubuntu server.I have followed all the steps and it even said BUILD SUCCESSFUL in the end but when I am running `./bin/spark-shell` it is giving me this error.[image]

It probably means that it is not able to locate .jar file which has location of ./spark-1.4.1/launcher/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/launcher which has all the java files like Main.java.

Also there is nothing in $CLASSPATH and $SPARK_CLASSPATH. I installed Spark in Linux and Mac before and was not faced with this problem. Can someone tell me what can be the problem here? Probably I need to specify classpath or some environment variable to point to a jar which contains all the class files.

My JAVA_HOME points to /jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre. Is there any problem with this?

EDIT: 
I tried few more things. I wrote a shell script to find out the jar file which contains the org/apache/spark/launcher/Main.class file and found out that it is located at : `/usr/local/src/spark/spark-1.4.1/launcher/target/spark-launcher_2.10-1.4.1.jar`. I changed my CLASSPATH and SPARK_CLASSPATH to the same location and tried running Spark. It gave me same error.

I also changed ./conf/spark-env.sh to incorporate different SPARK_CLASSPATH. It also didn't work.

Comment: How did you build your package? If you do a find in your SPARK_HOME do you see an assembly jar?

Comment: I used maven for building Spark as is mentioned on Spark website. i did `echo $SPARK_HOME` and it printed out blank line. I did `find . assembly.jar` from the Spark base directory and could not find anything.

Comment: Try setting SPARK_HOME to the directory where spark is installed.

Comment: you mean `export SPARK_HOME=/path/to/spark-1.4.1`

Comment: I did it but still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the spark-submit script from SPARK_HOME or another directory? The spark-submit script assumes you are running it from the SPARK_HOME directory.

Try setting the classpath to:
export CLASSPATH=${SPARK_HOME}/lib:$CLASSPATH
and try again.

Comment: my CLASSPATH is empty and I am running it from SPARK_HOME which is the folder spark-1.4.1

Comment: I did as you mentioned but it again gave the same error.

Comment: Changed the description of question with few things that I tried.

Answer (score 6):

SO after a lot of research and experiments, I found that I had been using wrong version of JDK. I should have been using JDK1.7 but I had been using default JAVA_HOME in ubuntu which is JDK-1.6.

Thus, install jdk1.7 and then point your java_home to it. Works fine after that.

Comment: I'm using CDH5.4 installed on Ubuntu trusty.   `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle-cloudera` fixed the problem